# How to call the first function after the second function is implemented in observable?

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

I have two functions and I want to call the `goBack()` function after `save()` is called.

```
  goBack(): void {
    this.location.back();
  }
  save(): void {
    this.employeeservice.updateEmployee(this.employees)
      .subscribe(res  => this.goBack());
  }
```

updateEmp :

```
updateEmployee(employee: Employee):Observable<Employee>{
                let headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
                let options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});
                const url= `${this.empurl}/${employee.id}`
                return this.http
                .put(url,JSON.stringify(employee),{headers: headers})
                .map(this.extractData)

                .catch(this.HandleErrorObservable)
            }
```

Employee-details.ts :

```
import {Component,OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {ActivatedRoute, Params} from '@angular/router';
import {Location} from '@angular/common';

import {Employee} from './employee';
import {EmployeeService} from './employee.service';





@Component ({ 
    selector: 'employee-detail',
    templateUrl: './employee-details.html'

})

export class EmployeeDetails {
    employees : Employee;

    constructor(
        private employeeservice : EmployeeService,
        private route : ActivatedRoute,
        private location : Location
        ){}

    ngOnInit(){
    this.route.params
      .switchMap((params: Params) => this.employeeservice.getEmployee(+params['id']))
      .subscribe(employees => this.employees = employees);
  }
goBack(): void {
    this.location.back();
  }
  save(): void {
    this.employeeservice.updateEmployee(this.employees)
      .subscribe(res  => {
        console.log('Back from save');
        this.goBack();
    });
  }

}
```

Employee-service.ts :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response,Headers,RequestOptions} from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import {Employee} from './employee'

@Injectable()
    export class EmployeeService {
            empurl = 'api/employees';
            constructor (private http:Http){}
            getDetailsFromJson():Observable<Employee[]>{
                return this.http.get(this.empurl)
                        .map(this.extractData)
                        .catch(this.HandleErrorObservable);                        
            }
            addEmployees(employee: Employee): Observable<Employee>{
                let headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
                let options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});
                return this.http.post(this.empurl,employee,options)
                        .map(this.extractData)
                        .catch(this.HandleErrorObservable)
            }
            delete(id : number){
                console.log(id);
    return this.http.delete(`${this.empurl}/${id}}, options`)

  }
            updateEmployee(employee: Employee):Observable<Employee>{
                let headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
                let options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});
                const url= `${this.empurl}/${employee.id}`
                return this.http
                .put(url,JSON.stringify(employee),{headers: headers})
                .map(this.extractData)

                .catch(this.HandleErrorObservable)
            }

            getEmployee(id : number){
                const url= `${this.empurl}/${id}`
                return this.http.get(url)
                .map(response => response.json().data as Employee)
                .catch(this.HandleErrorObservable)
            }


            private extractData(res: Response){
                let body= res.json();
                return body.data || []
            }
            private HandleErrorObservable(error : Response | any){
                console.log(error.message || error);
                return Observable.throw( error.message || error);
            }
    }
```

employee-deatils.html :

```
<div *ngIf="employees" > 


<div class="container" >
    <h1>{{employees.firstname}} details!</h1>
    <form class="form-horizontal" #employeeform="ngForm">
      <div class="form-group ">
        <label for="firstname" class="control-label col-md-3">FirstName:</label>
        <div class="col-md-6">
        <input type="text" class="form-control col-md-6" id="firstname" required [(ngModel)]="employees.firstname" name="firstname" >


      </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="lastname" class="control-label col-md-3">LastName:</label>
        <div class="col-md-6">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastname" required [(ngModel)]="employees.lastname" name="lastname">

        </div>
      </div>
     <button class="btn btn-default" (click)="goBack()" >Back</button>
      <button class="btn btn-success" (click)="save()" [disabled]="!employeeform.form.valid">Save</button>
      </form>
      </div>
</div>
```

In promises we would call it as `.then(() => this.goBack());` 
How do you call that in observable??

Comment: your code should work. is your subscribe not calling goback method ?

Comment: No . save() method is called but its not calling goback

Comment: @prasad, share the code of updateEmployee function

Comment: Update Employee is working but its not calling goBack() after that

Comment: Should work... Is your REST service returning any data? If not, you might return a boolean true from the REST service. I had issues when my rest services were returning null.

Comment: @birwin, even null is value. It seems like observable is never resolved

Comment: @missingmanual - Yes, I know know how null works. I was only saying that I was having similar issues with my observables when my REST call reply was empty.

Comment: So is there any solution for this?

Comment: @prasad - I have no idea if the null REST response is your issue. You will need to check what the REST call is returning in your "Developer Tools" Network tab. If it is empty, try altering the REST call to return a boolean and then see if that fixes your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems correct. Check if the `updateEmployee` method returns successfully. If you just want to test observable to make sure it's not stuck you can write something like:

```js
this.employeeservice.updateEmployee(this.employees)
    .subscribe(res => {
        console.log('Back from save');
        this.goBack();
    });
```

So now either you won't see your console log in which case there's something wrong with your observable or there's nothing in the previous state of the history.

Comment: I am not getting the console.log value

Comment: That means there's something wrong with `updateEmployee`. Unfortunately we can't help you unless you provide code for it as well.

Answer (score 0):

First verify that your updateEmployee method is working

```
 updateEmployee(employee: Employee):Observable<Employee>{
                    let headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
                    let options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});
                    const url= `${this.empurl}/${employee.id}`
                    return this.http
                    .put(url,JSON.stringify(employee),{headers: headers})
                    .map(this.extractData)
                    .subscribe(
                     data => console.log(data),
                       err => console.log(err),
                      () => console.log('working')
                         );
                }
```

if this function working and if your able see data in the console log than there is some issue with subscription.

if you have issue with subscription than remove providers in your component class and add in the module level.

still if your facing issue than post your component class

Comment: I am getting an error. `subscription is not assigned to type <observable>`

Comment: use this .map(res => res.json()) insted of .map(this.extractData)

Comment: I think its time create plunker